# Страница при первом посещении сайта

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать так, чтобы первые посетители сайта (stockup.az) перенаправлялись на лендинг, который рассказывает о сервисе (stockup.az/introduction), а пользователи которые уже бывали на сайте, переходили на домашнюю страницу (stockup.az). Возможно ли это как-то реализовать на PHP?

Comment: При первом посещении ставится кука. Если кука уже есть, то делается редирект куда нужно.

Comment: Подозреваю, что поисковикам это не очень понравится

Comment: @andreymal человек который задает такие вопросы, еще не может думать о том, как отреагируют поисковики)